# Actions on Google, what is the PACKAGE_NAME?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

I'm using Google's Api.ai and the Actions on Google console / SDK to create a simple Google Home app.

Currently stuck at the SDK init part:

#### Use Actions SDK to add actions to your Assistant app

`$ gactions update --action_package PACKAGE_NAME --project orderpizza-dbe00`

It automatically puts my project name after `--project`, however what is the `PACKAGE_NAME`?

Comment: Can you clarify why you're using the gactions command with API.AI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PACKAGE_NAME is the file name of your json file created by the 
`$ gactions init`


So assuming you are using the default name the update would be:
`$ gactions update --action_package action.json --project orderpizza-dbe00`